# What are the ways to skip some overload combinations of variant types in std::visit?

Tags: c++, c++17

`std::visit` supports multiple input variants. The code, however, should handle all combinations of the types from those variants.

Is there a way to skip not "meaningful" combinations?

for example:

```
template<class... Ts> 
struct overloaded : Ts... { using Ts::operator()...; };

template<class... Ts> overloaded(Ts...) -> overloaded<Ts...>;

int main() {
    std::variant<int, float, char> v1 { 's' };
    std::variant<int, float, char> v2 { 10 };

    std::visit(overloaded{
        [](int a, int b) { },
        [](int a, float b) { },
        [](int a, char b) { },
        [](float a, int b) { },
        [](float a, float b) { },
        [](float a, char b) { },
        [](char a, int b) { },
        [](char a, float b) { },
        [](char a, char b) { }
    }, v1, v2);

    return 0;
}
```

is there a chance to implement only several important combinations, and "leave" the rest?
(of course right now the compiler will report nasty error if you forget to implement one combination...)

maybe generic lambdas?

```
std::visit(overloaded{
        [](int a, int b) { },
        [](int a, float b) { },
        [](int a, char b) { },
        [](float a, int b) { },
        [](auto a, auto b) { }, // <<
    }, v1, v2);
```

That works, but I wonder if there's some better solution?

Update:
Here's the playground with the solutions mentioned in the answers:
http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/78d9f2f25789bad2

Comment: "maybe generic lambdas" Umm did you try that? Are you looking for another solution than generic lambdas?

Comment: generic lambdas should do the job.

Comment: yes, generic lambdas will work here, but I wonder if there's another solution. Generic lambdas should have lower precedence in the resolution set, so they will be chosen as the last resort... right?

Comment: Why don't you like generic lambdas here?

Comment: I like it, but wondering about other options. So maybe the whole question is not asked correctly.

Comment: and just like that with editing two words you made the question off-topic. "best way" is opinion based.

Comment: Was it better previously?

Comment: @fen yes it was

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Yes, generic lambdas are a very good solution. Your proposed solution literally works ad litteram.

Usual overload rules apply.

```
[](auto a, auto b)
```

is equivalent in this sense with

```
template <class T1, class T2> auto foo(T1 a, T2 b) const;
```

Anything that doesn't match exactly one of the non-templated overloads will call the generic lambda.

You can mix things up a bit by providing something like `[] (int a, auto b)` and `[] (auto a, auto b)`. Still  usual overload rules apply.

Or mix things up even more with `[]<class T>(T a, T b)` (since C++20)

Comment: is there anything else we can use here? and is it guaranteed to work?

Comment: @fen C variadics I guess

Comment: @Rakete1111 let's not go the C way :)

Comment: so it's guaranteed to work because concrete overloads will be always chosen as the best viable functions rather than the templated (generic lambda) versions.

Comment: @fen _is there anything else we can use here?_ Why go looking?  The generic lambda seems like an excellent solution to me.  And ... yes.

Comment: @fen yes. I am trying to think if there are any gotchas. The usual gotcha is that implicit conversion will go to the template, but it doesn't apply her because you have a clear type in the `std::variant`. So yes, it works as excepted (as far as I can see).

Comment: thanks, so generic lambdas seems to be the best way, and more expressive

Answer (score 3):

Another option would be to change `overloaded` to something like this:

```
template<class... Ts>
struct overloaded_or_no_op : Ts...
{
    using Ts::operator()...;

    template<class... Us>
    void operator()(const Us&...) const {  }
};

template<class... Ts> overloaded_or_no_op(Ts...) -> overloaded_or_no_op<Ts...>;
```

Comment: nice! so we can add some other functionalities to the overloaded pattern. In your example, users would have to provide only "interesting" implementations and skip the rest.

Comment: I'd prefer having a separate `nop` like `constexpr auto nop = [](auto const & ...){}` and then explicitly mention it in the overload set given to `overloaded`